# How to access, retrieve, store and delete files into a remote file server from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I am doing a project in node.js which involves storing an uploaded file from a client into a remote file server and can be retrieved it later. I know how to access and store files in a local file system using 'fs' . But I dont know how to do it with a remote file server.

Comment: You can use express and multer for file uploads

Comment: "Remote file server' could mean any of many different things. As you haven't even hinted at the type of file server you're using, this is far too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use express and multer for file uploads, this is coffeescript:

```
express = require 'express'
upload = require('multer')({dest: 'uploads/'})
fs = require 'fs'

files = express()

files.post '/', upload.single('file'),(req, res) ->
  console.log 'Receiving file...' + req.file.filename
  res.send 'Saved in uploads folder as' + req.file.filename

module.exports = files
```